# Wget or curl download file - Object moved error 302

Tags: php, curl, wget

I prefer if this could be done using wget otherwise update my curl code. I have searched a lot and tried many suggested options like cookies, referer url, user-agent.
Here is my code so far:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.symop.com/config/includes/common/dw.asp?PF=Publications&NF=symop_guide2013.pdf');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.symop.com/fr/Publications.asp");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $html;
```

302 Object Moved

Comment: The header `Location: http://www.symop.com?msg=msg_not_allowed` might by a hint.

Comment: Yeah, because something is wrong with the settings. When I open the url with my browser everything is working fine.